# Docker "hello world" example doesn't work. "no such file or directory"

Tags: ubuntu, linux-mint, docker

I'm totally new to playing around with Docker(.io) so I've just been RTFM'ing the main site, and hit a problem early on with their example "Hello world".  It seems like a few other folks have had the same symptom, but none of the fixes I've googled for have worked for me.

Environment: Linux Mint 17
Trying to follow the instructions here: http://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockerizing/

Basically:

$ sudo docker run ubuntu:14.04 /bin/echo 'Hello world'

The output of which (for me) is:

```
 #  sudo docker run ubuntu:14.04 /bin/echo 'Hello world'
 2014/07/25 07:39:22 no such file or directory
 #
```

I've installed docker following the steps in docs.docker.com.

More system information specific to docker, and the ubuntu image downloaded:

```
 # docker info
 Containers: 3
 Images: 11
 Storage Driver: aufs
  Root Dir: /var/lib/docker/aufs
  Dirs: 33
 Execution Driver: native-0.1
 Kernel Version: 3.13.0-32-generic
 WARNING: No swap limit support


 ComputerName ~ # docker version
 Client version: 0.9.1
 Go version (client): go1.2.1
 Git commit (client): 3600720
 Server version: 0.9.1
 Git commit (server): 3600720
 Go version (server): go1.2.1
 Last stable version: 1.1.2, please update docker


 ComputerName ~ # uname -a
 Linux ComputerName 3.13.0-32-generic #57-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jul 15 03:51:08 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux


 ComputerName ~ # docker images
 REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             VIRTUAL SIZE
 ubuntu              14.04               ba5877dc9bec        3 days ago          192.7 MB
 <none>              <none>              e54ca5efa2e9        5 weeks ago         276.5 MB
```

Any guidance greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you follow the troubleshooting here? http://docs.docker.com/installation/ubuntulinux/#troubleshooting

Comment: Yup.  Tried all of those before posting here.  cgroup-lite is installed and updated.  Originally had the DNS issue mentioned on that page,but fixed it already, and tried the ufw fix even though I'm not using ufw (figured it might have some effect any way).  No good.  But thanks for the suggestion, always good to RTFM first.  I'm just really surprised I'm getting this, following the 'hello world' example, as printed, on a pretty vanilla system. I've seen a few others report the symptom, but no conclusive fix yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the answer in an other Stack Overflow thread here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23205631/weird-error-while-running-docker-command-no-such-file-or-directory

FIX: **sudo apt-get install apparmor-utils** on the docker host system.

At least this fixed it for my particular error case.  Hope it is some use to others.

Answer (score 4):

When you install docker.io package, the guide tells you to create symlink to `/usr/bin/docker.io` in `/usr/local/bin/docker`. Then if you try to install latest version of Docker from docker.io repo, `lxc-docker` - the installation will remove `/usr/bin/docker.io` and symlink becomes invalid.

What you need to do to get it working again is to point symlink to `/usr/bin/docker`:

```
ln -sf /usr/bin/docker /usr/local/bin/docker
```

After that everything will be working.

Comment: Good thought, but not my issue. I made the symlink, as instructed  /usr/local/bin/docker -> /usr/bin/docker.io after the install.  So that isn't the issue.  Further, there is no "/usr/bin/docker" on my system, and creating one to link to /usr/bin/docker.io doesn't change any thing.  Thanks for the suggestions though.

Comment: Further, the command to the host os of "sudo docker..." executes the docker.io executable, as the /usr/local/bin/link is in path.  It's after docker starts up, that something inside the docker image, isn't finding some file being looked for.

Comment: I had this same issue with docker-compose.  Setting up the equivalent/analogous symlink also worked in my case also.